# AngularJS CheckItems selected Items to Delete as HTTP Request

Tags: angularjs, rest, checkbox

I want to use a Button Click, so when this Button gets clicked

```
<button type="button" ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
```

to use this function,

```
$scope.delete = function() {    


for( i=0; <each selected Item , i++)
```

I dont know how to code this in
Javascript, but lets say 10 Items are selected with the Checkbox 
and I want to make 10 Http Delete Requests the Parameter ID of the Selection
needed as a Parameter for the Rest Service . Username and Password are saved somewhere else.

```
$http.get("https://localhost/delete?username=" + $scope.email1 + "&password=" + $scope.password1 +&scope.selectedItemID).success(function(response)
}
    })
```

This is the Html File:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Object in ObjectList track by $index">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Object.isCheck" ng-change="checkChange(Object)"/>
        </td>   
                            <td>{{ Object.idObject}}</td>
                            <td>{{ Object.messageObject }}</td>         
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the delete function:

```
$scope.delete = function () {
    $scope.objectList.forEach(function (object) {
        if (object.isCheck) {
           // here you can do with the checked object what you want
        }
    })
};
```

Where I left the comment, you just need to call the `$http` service like you did. You have access to the full object, so you should also be able to access the objects ID.